# Get the values related to row in pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
            title          details
0     cake recipe         cake recipe comes here   
1     bread recipe         bread recipe comes here   
2     chocolate recipe        chocolate recipe comes here   
3     biscuit recipe      biscuit recipe comes here   
4     beans recipe       beans recipe comes here   
5  waffle recipe        waffle recipe comes here  
6  pudding recipe        pudding recipe comes here
```

I also have a list as follows.

```
mylist = [5, 2, 0]
```

I want to get `title` and `details` of the items in `mylist`. So, my output would look like below.

```
mydetails = ['waffle recipe. waffle recipe comes here', 'chocolate recipe chocolate recipe comes here', 'cake recipe cake recipe comes here']
```

My current code is as follows.

```
mydetails = []
v = df.loc[df.index.isin(mylist)]
item_details= v.title + '. ' + v.details
for val in item_details:
    mydetails.append(val)
```

However, the `v` I get is wrong. Please tell me how to fix this?

Comment: You should accept the answer that helped you most: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first select rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and then convert joined columns to `list`:

```
df = df.loc[mylist]
mydetails  = (df.title + '. ' + df.details).values.tolist()
print (mydetails )

['waffle recipe. waffle recipe comes here', 
 'chocolate recipe. chocolate recipe comes here', 
 'cake recipe. cake recipe comes here']
```

In your code is used [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), so order of values is default:

```
v = df.loc[df.index.isin(mylist)]
print (v)
              title                      details
0       cake recipe       cake recipe comes here
2  chocolate recipe  chocolate recipe comes here
5     waffle recipe     waffle recipe comes here
```

And for correct output remove `isin`:

```
mydetails = []
v = df.loc[mylist]
item_details= v.title + '. ' + v.details
for val in item_details:
    mydetails.append(val)

print (mydetails)
['waffle recipe. waffle recipe comes here', 
'chocolate recipe. chocolate recipe comes here', 
'cake recipe. cake recipe comes here']
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `list comprehension` to create the desired list:

```
mydetails = ["".join(df.values[n])    for n in mylist]
print(mydetails)
```

Output:

```
['waffle recipewaffle recipe comes here', 'chocolate recipechocolate recipe comes here', 'cake recipecake recipe comes here']
```

`df.values` is a list of all rows as lists. `"".join` is used to join both column values of each row.

To add a period and space between 2 entries, one can use `". ".join()`

Alternatively, one can add comma or semicolon as needed.